# Can I tell at compile time whether a specific set of input types to a Boost.Phoenix lambda is valid?

Tags: c++, boost, lambda, boost-phoenix

Say I have a Boost.Phoenix lambda expression, like the following:

```
_1 * 4.5 + (3.0 / _2)
```

Is there a good way to, at compile time, detect whether the lambda expression is valid, given a list of types associated with arguments `_1`, `_2`, and so on? I'm thinking that I would like to use `enable_if` to determine whether the input types are supported by the lambda. If so, the lambda would be invoked directly, while if not, I want to generate a no-op. Pseudocode would be something like this:

```
template <typename F, typename A1, typename A2>
enable_if<F::is_supported<A1, A2>, result_of<F(A1,A2)>::type >::type func(F func, A1 arg1, A2 arg2)
{
    func(A1, A2);
}

template <typename F, typename A1, typename A2>
disable_if<F::is_supported<A1, A2> >::type func(F func, A1 arg1, A2 arg2)
{
}
```

I'm just not sure how `is_supported` would be implemented, or whether it's even possible. I'm not using C++11; I would assume C++03 only (since Phoenix requires it).

Comment: "*I would assume C++03 only (since Phoenix requires it)*" Phoenix works fine with C++11.

Comment: @ildjam: Sorry, I didn't mean to imply that. I meant that Phoenix requires at least C++03, so to assume that as a minimum (as opposed to C++98).

Comment: This is easier to write in C++11, because SFINAE can be painful in C++03.  The "and so on" means you'll need to write a whole pile of different copy-pasta, because you lack variardic template support, or you'd need to mess around with boost preprocessor code generation, and I'm not about to do that on a lark.

Comment: Yeah, I figured that in order to support a wide range of arities, I would need to use Boost.Preprocessor to auto-generate all of the resulting boilerplate code. I can handle that part; I'm just trying to figure out whether, for a specific arity, I can do what I proposed above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think it's possible in Phoenix as it stands today. To support this use, `enable_if` would have had to have been used on virtually every function call Phoenix makes in the eval call chain, at every level, even in the other libraries Phoenix depends on. I know Phoenix isn't written that way, and its hard to imagine that any amount of hacking on the code could make it so, before Phoenix, Proto, and all the libraries they depend on are rewritten in pure C++11. Even then, it would require great care that all potential errors appear in a SFINAE content.

I just don't see it happening, sorry.

Comment: Thanks for your input; I surely trust your opinion. I may tinker with my requirements a little more to see if I can get anything workable. Alternatively, I may be able to build what I want using Boost.Proto directly.

Comment: I hesitate even to recommend this, as the code is still evolving,  but my C++11 rewrite of Proto might be a better starting point: https://github.com/ericniebler/proto-0x. It's undocumented and in constant flux. Caveat emptor.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but I can't rely upon C++11 availability for this application. I had a thought for a different angle, however: I've been reading through the introductory documentation for Proto, which I understand is the basis for Phoenix 3.0. Would it be possible to use the `proto::matches<>` metafunction in some way to accomplish what I want to do at compile time? It seems that the question, as I've posed it, would yield an invalid expression according to the lambda's grammar if the input types aren't supported. I might be way off here, but you're the expert, so I thought I'd ask.

Comment: I don't think `proto::matches<>` helps you here. You want to know whether an expression `a + b / (c - d)` compiles for variables of some specified types. You can't do this reliably without c++11's `decltype` and generalized SFINAE for expressions.